# django rest framework: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can't find the bug please help

I also tried this with custom models *didn't worked*.
As you can see I'm tring to do PUT, DELETE and GET opration.

**Error Message**

> Exception Type: TypeError at /api/user/sagar/Exception Value: unhashable type: 'list'

**views.py**

```
class ProfileApiView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializer.RegisterUserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    lookup_field = ['username']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(username=self.request.user)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class RegisterUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True, validators=[
                                   UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, validators=[
                                     UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: Please provide a complete traceback, so we can see the file/line where the error occurs

Comment: can you replace `lookup_field = ['username']` with `lookup_field = 'username'` and retry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview):

> `lookup_field` - The model field that should be used to for performing object lookup of individual model instances. Defaults to 'pk'.

It expects a field (as string) and not a list.

So replace:

`lookup_field = ['username']`

by

`lookup_field = 'username'`